# Compiling Error java.io.IOExeption error must be caught or declared

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors, java-io

This is a new error I haven't seen before, I would be so grateful for some help

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InClass_Module_5 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     //char choice;
     String vehicle1, vehicle2, vehicle3, vehicle4, anStr;
     vehicle1 = "Mercedes-Benz C350 Sport Sedan";
     vehicle2 = "Volkswagen Touareg";
     vehicle3 = "Nissan Murano";
     vehicle4 = "Ford F-150";
     anStr = " is a perfect vehicle for you!";


     System.out.println("Enter the letter corresponding to the vehicle you would like to own:");
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     char choice;

  System.out.print("\nEnter the letter corresponding to the vehicle you would like to own: ");
  choice = (char)System.in.read();

  if(choice >= 'A' && choice <= 'D')
   //choice += 32;

  if(choice >= 'a' && choice <= 'd')
   //choice -= 32; 

     System.out.println("A. " + vehicle1);
     System.out.println("B. " + vehicle2);
     System.out.println("C. " + vehicle3);
     System.out.println("D. " + vehicle4);



     System.out.println("You chose letter: " + choice);

     if (choice == 'A') {
      System.out.println("The " + vehicle1 + anStr);
     } else if (choice == 'B'){
      System.out.println("The " + vehicle2 + anStr);
     } else if (choice == 'C') {
      System.out.println("The " + vehicle3 + anStr);
     } else if (choice == 'D') {
      System.out.println("The " + vehicle4 + anStr);
     } else {
      System.out.println("You made an in-valid selection and will not be driving anything today!");
     }


}
}
```

**Error**:

> 1 error found: File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module
>   4/InClass_Module_5.java  [line: 31] Error:
>   /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module
>   4/InClass_Module_5.java:31: unreported exception java.io.IOException;
>   must be caught or declared to be thrown

Thank you in advance

Comment: You really need to use `{` and `}` after your `if` statements, to clarify which lines of code should only run when the `if` condition comes out true.  Otherwise, you're going to get some nasty surprises with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your line 31 in a try/catch block like so:

```
try
{
    // Whatever your line 31 is
}
catch(java.io.IOException)
{
    // Your error handling code
}
```

Certain methods are specified to throw certain Exceptions (errors) when something goes wrong. Those exceptions must be caught and handled by a try/catch block in order to isolate the Exception and keep it from cascading throughout your code. See the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

The statement `System.in.read();` can throw an `IOException` which is a checked exception, meaning that your code is required to treat the exception in case it is thrown.

Either catch the exception in your code, or declare that `main` can throw this exception. The right approach depends on what you want to do if the exception is thrown: if you want the program to terminate with an error, just declare that `main` `throws` `IOException`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```

Otherwise, catch the exception and handle it according to your need.

On a different note, you are creating a `Scanner` object but not using it (you should get a warning message for it). If you don't need it just remove it.

Comment: but she has Scanner variable name in and use System.in so confusing

Comment: as far as I know it is bad practice to throws any exception in main method

Comment: I would recommend using try with resources for the Scanner.

Comment: @KickButtowski Indeed OP is defining a `Scanner` and not using it.

Comment: Thank you guys, I ended up using Scanner. I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're asking for input with your scanner, and stuff can go wrong, so basically it wants you to implement a 'backup plan' so to speak. you can Either throw an exception:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{...
```

or you can use a try/catch block, which will try something, :

```
  try {
      choice = (char)System.in.read();
  } catch ( IOException e ) {
      System.out.println("Oh no! better clean up!");
      in.close();
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

The try/catch statement here tries to do whats in the 'try{...}' block, and if that fails, it does what's in the 'catch{...}' block.

Answer (score 0):

At least you can replace this

```
choice = (char)System.in.read();
```

by this

```
choice = in.next().charAt(0);
choice = Character.toLowerCase(choice);
```

So you are only taking the first char of the input user and then changing the case to lower